# Obtain Array Data variable - Laravel - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a Variable `$deliveryname` Array with the following information

```
    [
   {
      "id":7,
      "name":"Delivery2",
      "email":"delibery2@hotmail.com",
      "email_verified_at":null,
      "password":"$2y$10$SID2yPM.hNsgHCCFh3BeXuk1Bylqsxl39DXPdYaXKZ00FvzSXCJju",
      "remember_token":null,
      "created_at":"2021-06-15 05:07:16",
      "updated_at":"2021-06-15 05:07:16",
      "auth_token":null,
      "phone":"456465465",
      "default_address_id":0,
      "delivery_pin":"Y11FN",
      "delivery_guy_detail_id":3,
      "avatar":null,
      "is_active":1,
      "tax_number":null
   }
]
```

I need to get the key "name" value that would be "Delivery2"

I have this code to create the variable in php but it doesn't work

```
$deliveryname2 = $deliveryname["name"];
```

Use Laravel

Comment: `$deliveryname2 = $deliveryname[0]["name"];` maybe?..

Comment: $deliveryname2 = $deliveryname[0]["name"];

Comment: $result=json_decode($deliveryname); $result[0]["name"];

Comment: "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" error result

Comment: probable [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decode `json` to get `array` or `object`

```
 $deliveryname='[
   {
      "id":7,
      "name":"Delivery2",
      "email":"delibery2@hotmail.com",
      "email_verified_at":null,
      "password":"$2y$10$SID2yPM.hNsgHCCFh3BeXuk1Bylqsxl39DXPdYaXKZ00FvzSXCJju",
      "remember_token":null,
      "created_at":"2021-06-15 05:07:16",
      "updated_at":"2021-06-15 05:07:16",
      "auth_token":null,
      "phone":"456465465",
      "default_address_id":0,
      "delivery_pin":"Y11FN",
      "delivery_guy_detail_id":3,
      "avatar":null,
      "is_active":1,
      "tax_number":null
   }
]';

   $result=json_decode($deliveryname);
   dd($result[0]->name);
```

To get array then you have pass additional `param` to `json_decode`  to `true`

```
 $result=json_decode($deliveryname,true);
   dd($result[0]['name']);
```

Comment: First of all I thank you too much !!
It worked only missing the [0]
What does that [0] mean? Why is it there?

Comment: you have multidimensional array so . usually multidimensional array retrieved using loop . check for php array types.so you get basic idea

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_decode`

```
<?php
 $deliveryname='[{
      "id":7,
      "name":"Delivery2",
      "email":"delibery2@hotmail.com",
      "email_verified_at":null,
      "password":"$2y$10$SID2yPM.hNsgHCCFh3BeXuk1Bylqsxl39DXPdYaXKZ00FvzSXCJju",
      "remember_token":null,
      "created_at":"2021-06-15 05:07:16",
      "updated_at":"2021-06-15 05:07:16",
      "auth_token":null,
      "phone":"456465465",
      "default_address_id":0,
      "delivery_pin":"Y11FN",
      "delivery_guy_detail_id":3,
      "avatar":null,
      "is_active":1,
      "tax_number":null
   }]';

    $result=json_decode($deliveryname);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
  
?>
```

[DEMO](https://paiza.io/projects/TuRzUNtQXmPp4Zo_n5PVDg)